# "andr" tab completes to "_xrandr" instead of android or nothing

Tags: android, macos, zsh, tab-completion, oh-my-zsh

I am running osx and installed oh-my-zsh as well, if that's relevant.

Anyway, if I type in something like "andr" and hit tab to complete it, it autocompletes to `_xrandr` instead of doing nothing (`android` isn't in my path). I'm not really sure why.

Any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: Do the `android` command is in your path ?

Comment: It's not, but should that be relevant? Shouldn't it just not do anything? (Just fixed the question title to reflect that)

Comment: So, if it's not in your path, `zsh` can't complete it ! You can add the command by editing your `.zshrc` with `export PATH=$PATH:<path/to/android/command/directory>`

Comment: I get that, what I don't get is why it autocompletes to `_xrandr` instead of just not doing anything

Comment: Because zsh wants to pick something, and _xrandr is in your path. What's not to get?

Comment: AH okay, I didn't get that. It's probably because your configuration say to complete with the closest command, if it not find a command start with what you write.

Comment: But then how come if I type in something else, like `ddm`, it doesn't autocomplete to anything?

Comment: Ah. Okay. So sort of like a fuzzy matching? Any idea where zsh specifies that setting?

Comment: A nice answer and explanation here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116176/zsh-auto-complete-suggest-complete-functions-git-vim-etc --note this doesn't include the extra wrinkles introduced with oh-my-zsh, though I believe Adaephon's answer addresses these.

Answer (score 2):

*oh-my-zsh* sets up completion to look for completions on the left side of the typed word if there are none on the right side.

This happens in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.zsh`:

```
## case-insensitive (all),partial-word and then substring completion
if [ "x$CASE_SENSITIVE" = "xtrue" ]; then
  zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
  unset CASE_SENSITIVE
else
  zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
fi
```

The important part here is `'l:|=* r:|=*'`. If you dislike this behavior, you just have to remove this from `zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list`. The best way to do this, is to create a file in `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom` with extension `.zsh`, for example `own-completion.zsh`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*'
```

This is for case insensitive completion, if you do not want this either, also remove `'m:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'`.

You could change it in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.zsh` directly, but it will probably be overwritten once you update *oh-my-zsh*.