# Oh My Zsh - remove extra space inserted when typing asterisk

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

Here is the scenario. Let's say I am in a directory ("Downloads")

[image]

Now I type `rm -rf` and press the **tab** key for the list of files to show up. So I get:

[image]

I press **tab** again (three times) and select `file1`

[image]

Notice that the cursor is just after last character of `file1`. Now I type `*` after it. What I get is this:

[image]

oh-my-zsh automatically inserts an extra space between `file1` and `*`. This is disastrous because it will delete all files and folders in this directory. I have lost a bunch of files multiple times because of this behavior of oh-my-zsh. This does not exist in the default zsh shell. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If there's a bug in oh-my-zsh you need to report it to the maintainers.

Comment: Playing around with this, I was able to get the default `zsh` behavior by commenting out the line `zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:*' menu select` in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.zsh`. I have no idea what that option does - if you figure it out, please post an answer here.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24359779/) has some information on how to make changes to `omz` that will survive any future updates.

Comment: FYI this belongs on SuperUser, not Stack Overflow (it's general computing, not programming-related).  Also, it's really important to include properly-formatted text, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for reasons why this is important.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Oops! Sorry. I will be careful next time.